# Perform a SQL search on a button click with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I am currently creating a login system so that when the user clicks the login button my "Employee" table is searched and if the entered ID is not found in the table an error message is printed, however, I keep receiving this error -

"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'"

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

global employeeIDVar

win = Tk()
img = PhotoImage( file = 'download_1_.gif' )
imgLbl = Label ( win, image = img)

frame1=Frame(win)
frame1.pack()
Label(frame1, text="Welcome to the system!",font=('Comic Sans MS',18)).grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(frame1, text="EmployeeID").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
employeeIDVar=IntVar(win)
eID= Entry(frame1, textvariable=employeeIDVar)
eID.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

frame2 = Frame(win)
frame2.pack()

b1= Button(frame2, text=" Login ")
b2= Button(frame2, text=" Quit ")
b1.pack(side=LEFT); b2.pack(side=LEFT)

def login(id):
    with sqlite3.connect("comicBookGuys.db") as db:

            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute ("select employeeID, numberOfSales, salesTarget from Employee where employeeID=?", (id,))
            dataFound = cursor.fetchone()
            return dataFound    

            if not dataFound:
                messagebox.showinfo("No such employeeID found! Try again.")

def logEnd():
    exit()

b1.configure(command=login)
b2.configure(command=logEnd)
win.mainloop()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error looks pretty self-explanatory: you've defined `login` to require a parameter, but the button isn't passing that parameter.

Comment: Everytime i try pass a parameter I get - sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way GUIs are typically written is that you don't pass information in callbacks. Instead, the callback requests information from the UI when it is executed.

In your case I recommend you remove the parameter for `login`, and modify `login` to fetch the information when it is called.

For example:

```
def login():
    id = eID.get()
    ...
```

Comment: Working perfectly now, thanks very much for the help!